# Stability of carbocation on doubly bonded carbon

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbocation

[image]

What can be said about the stability of the following carbocation?

---

I think that it would have something to do with hybridisation as, clearly one carbon is sp hybridised and the other is sp2.

Can anyone confirm this or elaborate on this?

Also what would happen if the Hydrogens are all replaced by a carbon chain?
And what if there's positive charge on both the given carbons?

Comment: stability can only be compared not determined

Comment: Look here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinyl_cation. Note: either you present an empirical formula or you place the + on the C without octet.